# What would be the best way to count repeating character strings in a vector using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

Im getting long lists of various repeating character strings in my script. I want to reduce each consecutive repeating string to simply the string once followed by (#x). The (#x) corresponding to the number of times the character string is repeated

```
summarise(Path = paste0(Channel, collapse = " > ")
```

the above snippet is part of my user path statement and provides an output of something like this for each record: 
`Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Direct > Endpage > Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Endpage > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Direct`

I expect the output to be something like this so doing it manually in excel is no longer needed!!
`Direct (3x) > Endpage > Direct > Endpage > Direct (3x) > Endpage (2x) > Direct (11x) > Endpage > Direct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt<-"Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Direct > Endpage > Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Endpage > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Direct > Endpage > Direct"
tt<-rle(strsplit(txt, " > ")[[1]])
res<-""
for (i in 1:length(tt$values)) {
  res<-paste0(res, ifelse(i>1, " > ", ""), tt$values[i], ifelse(tt$lengths[i]>1, paste0("(X", tt$lengths[i],")"), ""))
}
```

Result:

```
res
[1] "Direct(X3) > Endpage > Direct > Endpage > Direct(X3) > Endpage(X2) > Direct(X11) > Endpage > Direct"
```

Or, if you want it as a function:

```
shorten<-function(txt) {tt<-rle(strsplit(txt, " > ")[[1]])
  res<-""
  for (i in 1:length(tt$values)) {
    res<-paste0(res, ifelse(i>1, " > ", ""), tt$values[i], ifelse(tt$lengths[i]>1, paste0("(X", tt$lengths[i],")"), ""))
  }
  res
}

shorten(txt)
[1] "Direct(X3) > Endpage > Direct > Endpage > Direct(X3) > Endpage(X2) > Direct(X11) > Endpage > Direct"
```

If you want to apply this to a column of strings, try:

```
lapply(data$column, shorten)
```

PS - just for the fun of it I came up with a single line alternative:

```
shorten2<-function(txt) gsub(" 1 "," ",paste(apply(sapply(rle(strsplit(txt, " > ")[[1]]), paste),1,function(x) paste(x, collapse=" ")),collapse=" > "))
```

But it turns out this solution, which avoids a for loop but introduces two `*apply`s, is actually marginally slower on a 500-row column:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 forloop 64.85126 66.08620 76.05589 68.54179 69.89208 191.8934   100
    gsub 71.98645 73.45945 81.75625 75.83651 77.32290 186.3958   100
```

Comment: Awesome! how would this change in order to be applied to a column of a data table with thousands of rows?

Comment: Each row having a single string?

Comment: each row having a list of strings similar to the above 'txt' object you named

Comment: see above - just use the function format, and run `lapply(data$column, shorten)`. The result would be a list of all the shortened strings, which you can then assign back to the dataframe.

Comment: (added one-line alternative, but turns out it wasn't worth it)